# How to set hotkeys on function keys

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

I have a multi-boot laptop (Clevo NS50MU) with Linux Mint and Windows, with a keyboard that uses function keys for volume and brightness control but only when Fn is pressed. I want to control volume/brightness when the corresponding function keys are pressed without pressing Fn, and map to the function keys themselves when they are pressed while Fn is held down.

I was easily able to do this for volume on Windows, using Sharpkeys to change the registry. For example, pressing F5 would decrease volume, and pressing Fn+F5 would refresh. My trouble is, I can't get this to work for brightness keys and I have limited success with volume keys on Linux.

On Windows, Sharpkeys allows you to set volume keys and function keys, but there is no option labelled as the brightness key. When I open the window that detects keyboard input, pressing multimedia keys of any kind redirects to multimedia functions and Sharpkeys doesn't detect it. So is there a way to change brightness key functionality using Sharpkeys? If not, what would I need to do in the registry to change that like volume was changed?

On Linux, I have had very little success. I have tried using xbindkeys which is configured by a .xbindkeysrc file, which includes the following:

```
"killall xbindkeys && xdotool key F3 && xbindkeys"
  XF86AudioMute

"killall xbindkeys && xdotool key XF86AudioMute && xbindkeys"
  F3

"killall xbindkeys && xdotool key F5 && xbindkeys"
  XF86AudioLowerVolume

"killall xbindkeys && xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume && xbindkeys"
  F5

"killall xbindkeys && xdotool key F6 && xbindkeys"
  XF86AudioRaiseVolume

"killall xbindkeys && xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume && xbindkeys"
  F6
```

The problem is it only works for volume and not brightness control, and even then it requires repeated presses to change volume instead of continuing to change when a key is held, I assume because xbindkeys is constantly being killed. So this is a sub-satisfactory option. I have also tried using input remapper and xmodmap which I assumed would work similarly to registry-editing hotkey applications I've used on Windows. No success however; keys either lose all functionality or only have one action.

Linux Mint seems to be making it impossible to map any keys or buttons that I want it to map, no matter what I try. It's especially disappointing considering Windows can do this easily but Mint seems to fail at doing the same thing. Any possible way forward or reason what I'm doing doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but I just want to answer this question anyway, it may help others.

You are looking in the wrong place. Fn key functionality settings are within the BIOS and not your operating system.

Of course the BIOS is different on every device, but for reference here is how it looks on an HP laptop. (BIOS setup > Advanced > System options)
[image: HP Fn keys in bios]

Comment: Thanks but I don't have that option in my BIOS. I ended up just setting Alt + ... key combos for volume and playback control on Linux.